# IOS Notification when charging

Tags: ios, background, notifications, apple-push-notifications

is possible to get notifications from an App when for exemple :

- I plug the charger?
- I am at 100% of charge?

Is it possible then to get an action to be done from this notification ?

And, last one : is it possible to have this notification even if my app is not running ? Just like I receive push notification when I get a Whatsapp message ?

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor the battery's level and status with [this code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Listings/BatteryStatus_BatStatViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812-BatteryStatus_BatStatViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6).

```
float batteryLevel = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel; //gets the battery's level
UIDeviceBatteryState currentState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState; //gets the battery's status

// Register for battery level and state change notifications.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(batteryLevelChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(batteryStateChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

You can use those notifications to trigger whatever event you want (like local notifications).
However, you won't be able to monitor anything if your app is not running (either in the foreground or the background).

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks a lot for your answer. Background : can it be like Viber or Whatsapp kind of background (notifications of message even if App is not launched), or does the app have to be launched and remain in the background ?

Comment: The Whatsapp like notifications are Push. They are sent from Whatsapp's server and will be showed by iOS even if the app is terminated. In your case, you need to execute code on the device to get the battery status. It can't happen if your app is terminated.

Comment: ok. I see. Push notifications are only from Servers and not from the IOS or device! This is what I didn't understand so far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have Local Notifications that look like Push notifications. But while you can schedule to trigger them, you won't be able to actively display one if your app is not running.